# Extract a column value from a spark dataframe and add it to another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe called "df_array" it will always returns a single array as an output like below.

```
arr_value
[M,J,K]
```

I want to extract it's value and add to another dataframe.
below is the code I was executing

```
val new_df = old_df.withColumn("new_array_value", df_array.col("UNCP_ORIG_BPR"))
```

but my code always fails saying "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s)"

Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 1):

The operation needed here is `join`

You'll need to have the a common column in both dataframes, which will be used as "key".

After the join you can `select` which columns to be included in the new dataframe.

More detailed can be found here: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

**join(other, on=None, how=None)**

```
Joins with another DataFrame, using the given join expression.
Parameters: 

    other – Right side of the join
    on – a string for the join column name, a list of column names, a join expression (Column), or a list of Columns. If on is a string or a list of strings indicating the name of the join column(s), the column(s) must exist on both sides, and this performs an equi-join.
    how – str, default ‘inner’. One of inner, outer, left_outer, right_outer, leftsemi.

The following performs a full outer join between df1 and df2.

>>> df.join(df2, df.name == df2.name, 'outer').select(df.name, df2.height).collect()
[Row(name=None, height=80), Row(name=u'Bob', height=85), Row(name=u'Alice', height=None)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `df_array` has only *one* record, you can collect it to driver using `first()` and then use it as an array of **literal values** to create a column in any DataFrame:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// first - collect that single array to driver (assuming array of strings):
val arrValue = df_array.first().getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]](0)

// now use lit() function to create a "constant" value column:
val new_df = old_df.withColumn("new_array_value", array(arrValue.map(lit): _*)) 

new_df.show()
// +--------+--------+---------------+
// |old_col1|old_col2|new_array_value|
// +--------+--------+---------------+
// |       1|       a|      [M, J, K]|
// |       2|       b|      [M, J, K]|
// +--------+--------+---------------+
```